# Change Xaml-Image.Source from a new Class (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

im new to Xamarin and i try to change the Image.Source from a Xaml.Page via a new class. Maybe someone can help me out with this.

e.g
I have a **PageX.xaml** with a **Image x:Name="ImageX"** and a new **ClassY**

Now i would like to change the **ImageX.Source** from **PageX** when circumstance **Z** occurs.

Some insights on my code:

**Xaml:**

```
<Image
   x:Name="ImageNonBossAnimation"
   BackgroundColor="Transparent"
   Grid.Row="18"
   Grid.RowSpan="10"
   Grid.Column="20"
   Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
/>
```

**new Class:**

```
public static async void AttackSkills(string pressedSkill, string monsterType)
{
   if (pressedSkill == "SkillX")
      {
         if (monsterType == "nonBoss")
            {
               for (int animCounter = 1; animCounter <= 6; animCounter++)
                   {
                       PageX.ImageNonBossAnimation.Source = "anim_stroke" + animCounter.ToString();
                       await Task.Delay(30);
                   }
                   Page.ImageNonBossAnimation.Source = null;
            }
            --another occasion takes place here--
      }
}
```

I really would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Have you structured you code using MVVM concept, which is the preferred method for Xamarin apps?

Comment: You are on PageY when Z circumstance occurs and you want PageX.Image to change?

Comment: @ChrisBD thanks for your answer. I guess i´m not using the MVVM concept. I´m using the normal Xamarin ContentPage where you got a linked .cs.

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi I´m on PageX, calling a new classY. I want to change the PageX.Image with the function in classY. Hope  that answers your question. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @CodeSeekers i found a Solution.

It´s relatively easy, you can call your new **class Y** from the .cs bound to your .xaml with:

**Code in .cs**

```
ClassY.AttackSkills(passedSkill, monsterType, ImageX);
```

**class Y Code**

```
public static async void AttackSkills(string pressedSkill, string monsterType, Image ImageNonBossAnimation)
    {
        if (pressedSkill == "SkillX")
        {
            if (monsterType == "nonBoss")
            {
                for (int animCounter = 1; animCounter <= 6; animCounter++)
                {
                    ImageX.Source = "anim_stroke" + animCounter.ToString();
                    await Task.Delay(30);
                }
                ImageX = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageNonBossAnimation is not a static Item in PageX , So you can't access it like PageX.ImageNonBossAnimation
pass Image as reference to AttackSkills this method and then change image source.
Like

```
public static async void AttackSkills(string pressedSkill, string monsterType, ref Image ximgae)
{
   if (pressedSkill == "SkillX")
      {
         if (monsterType == "nonBoss")
            {
               for (int animCounter = 1; animCounter <= 6; animCounter++)
                   {
                       ximage.Source = "anim_stroke" + animCounter.ToString();
                       await Task.Delay(30);
                   }
                   ximage.Source = null;
            }
            --another occasion takes place here--
      }
}
```

and call method like `AttackSkills(parem1,parem2,ref ImageNonBossAnimation);`

Comment: thanks for clarifiying, just need to mention if you´re using "async" you can use "ref"